# The property of a variable that is either discrete or continuous

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

For example, the arity property of a function might be unary or binary.  The (???) property of a variable might be discrete or continuous?

Comment: Depending on what you're talking about (_discrete_ ~ _continuous_ is a cline that covers a **lot** of semantic territory), one could speak of _dimensionality_ (points are discrete, lines are continuous), _granularity_ (_stones_ ~ _stone; beans_ ~ _rice_), _subcategorization_ (_weigh `X`_ ~ _count `X`_), etc. See Frawley's [_Linguistic Semantics_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/frawleyq.pdf) for available categories, like the ones for [Entities](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/FrawleyEntities.pdf), i.e, "nouns".

Comment: Have you tried asking on [math.se] ? I think it's OT here.

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't recognize the word ***arity***, I looked it up. OED defines it as

> The number of elements by virtue of which something is unary, binary, etc.
>    First citation (emphasis mine):
>    *1968 ...the order of **enlargeability** and the arity or the order of **reducibility** of abstract algebras*

In light of that I'm inclined to favour an **-ability** type of word. The first one that came to mind was *quantisability* - which you probably won't find in any dictionaries (yet! :), but which I would naturally understand as...

> ***quantisability*** - an attribute defining whether/to what extent something can be quantized
>    ...from...
>    ***quantize*** - to approximate (a signal *varying continuously* in amplitude) by one whose amplitude is restricted to a prescribed set of *discrete values*. (Again, emphasis mine)

It's my understanding that if a variable can be *quantized*, it's *digital/discrete*. If not, it's *continuous*.

Answer (score -1):

A variable can only take on one value at a time.  Therefore it is neither discrete nor continuous.  It just has a value.